# uploading to a relative folder to a asp.net server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

i use to upload a photo to a server this piece of code:

```
uplTheFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path);
```

But the Path can't be relative (like `~\\Photos\\image.jpg`) .

I was thinking of getting the location of the .aspx file from where i upload the image and attach `\\Photos\\image.jpg` to it, but i don't know how to get the address (location ) of my .aspx page on the server .

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Server.MapPath("~/Photos/image.jpg");
```

That will give you the physical path. You could have the aspx file name in there if you wanted:

```
Server.MapPath("~/mypage.aspx");
```

The `Page` object also has a property that points to the template file (the aspx)